# gdb in sublime text 3: debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints and exits immediately

Tags: c++, gdb, sublimetext3

I've setup SublimeGDB by following the instructions on the github page. It wasn't running so I included a .sublime-project file to the specifications outlined here: https://thenigh7sh4de.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/setting-up-sublimegdb/ .

I'm able to set breakpoints, but when I press f5 to run I see the SublimeGDB interface flicker and then disappear, with the message "GDB Session Ended".

My particular c++ program takes `cin` input and it doesn't seem to display. My build system is C++ Single File and I'm running in Ubuntu.

Comment: I'd recommend first trying it outside of Sublime.  This will tell you if it is a bug in gdb (e.g., if gdb crashes) or a bug in Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile your executable with debug information included by adding -g option to the GDB command line which is not being added by default by Sublime Text C++ build system. Check this answer for more details how to do it.